# why the 3 stage differential opamp not worked

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge

i did the following in simulation its work.
but in practically, i cannot able to get a amplified output.
i use ic741 as a op-amp 5v input for opamp and bridge power supply... i get always 1.77v in my output side for all kind of input.
give me a suggestion.
[image]

Comment: The TI data sheet for the 741 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf says the minimum operating voltage is +/-10 V, are you just powering it with a single 5 V rail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP was powering the circuit insufficiently. That's the equivalent to a typo – thus, this question bears no future value.

Comment: [Reasons **NOT** to use a 741](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522)

Answer (score 1):

The LM741 is a very old OP-Amp. It has no rail-to-rail feature.
So you can easily subtract (add) 2 volts from (to) every rail to get the remaining usable voltage range. If every stage can only use 1 V for amplification, the whole circuit is rather unlikely to work as you may guess.

If you look into the datasheet of the LM741, you can clearly see, that the minimum recommended voltage is +-10 V. Next time, read the datasheet before designing a circuit and check the relevant figures.

Now you may ask, why your simulation does not reflect the OP-amps behaviour? Simply spoken, the OPs behaviour in operating conditions which are outside the recommended values is highly nonlinear and unpredictable. Implementing this behaviour in a simulation model is a very high effort with little benefit.

Comment: but first i check with 12v supply for op-amp at the time also i cannot able to get respected output. i shows 3.14 v for all inputs..... i will correct with 5v

Comment: @Raj_1 - Note that "+-10 V" does **not** mean "about 10V". it means "+10V **and** -10V" - that's 20V from end to end.

Comment: thanks sir. i correct my mistake. my amplifier circuit is working. can u suggets any 4-20ma coverter for my 1-5v. because i have to give the 4-20ma for plc as a input